# Pandas split a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe where I want to split the Col2 into multiple columns:

Input DataFrame:

```
>>> mydf= pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['AA','AB','AAC'], 'Col2':['AN||Ind(0.9)','LN||RED(8.9)','RN||RED(9.8)'], 'Col3':['log1','log2','log3']})

>>> mydf
   Col1      Col2      Col3
0   AA  AN||Ind(0.9)  log1
1   AB  LN||RED(8.9)  log2
2  AAC  RN||RED(9.8)  log3
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
  Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4  Col5
0   AA   AN  log1  Ind   0.9
1   AB   LN  log2  RED   8.9
2  AAC   RN  log3  RED   9.8
```

I started with Apply but the following will take a good few steps. Any shortcut?

```
mydf['Col4']=mydf['Col2'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('||')[0])
```

Also little confused why the following throws a valuerror:

```
mydf['Col2'].str.split('||', expand=True)

ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split out the columns with `str.extract` and `assign`

```
regex = '(?P<Col2>.*)\|{2,}(?P<Col4>.*)\((?P<Col5>.*)\)'
mydf.assign(**mydf.Col2.str.extract(regex, expand=True).to_dict('list'))

  Col1 Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5
0   AA   AN  log1  Ind  0.9
1   AB   LN  log2  RED  8.9
2  AAC   RN  log3  RED  9.8
```

Or equivalently with `combine_first`

```
regex = '(?P<Col2>.*)\|{2,}(?P<Col4>.*)\((?P<Col5>.*)\)'
mydf.Col2.str.extract(regex, expand=True).combine_first(mydf)

  Col1 Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5
0   AA   AN  log1  Ind  0.9
1   AB   LN  log2  RED  8.9
2  AAC   RN  log3  RED  9.8
```

***explanation***

This uses a regular expression to parse the `Col2` values and assign column names at the same time

```
regex = '(?P<Col2>.*)\|{2,}(?P<Col4>.*)\((?P<Col5>.*)\)'
```

- `'(?P<Col2>.*)\|{2,}'` will grab everything up to the first double `|` and call it `Col2`
- `'(?P<Col4>.*)'` grabs everything up to the parentheses and calls it `Col4`
- `'\((?P<Col5>.*)\)'` grabs everything inside the parentheses and calls it `Col5`
- finally, we either reassign `Col2` overwriting the existing `Col2` or we use `combine_first` where we default to the newly formulated `Col2` values.

Answer (score 2):

@piRSquared answer is amazing as usual and upvoted, I am just posting my approach. I just kept it very simple

```
mydf[['Col2', 'Col4', 'Col5']]= mydf.Col2.str.extract('(.*?)\|\|(.*?)\((.*?)\)', expand = True)
```

Col2 is automatically reassigned so no need to drop a column later.

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
0   AA      AN      log1    Ind     0.9
1   AB      LN      log2    RED     8.9
2   AAC     RN      log3    RED     9.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Using RegEx from [the great @piRSquared's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43458901/5741205)

```
In [59]: regex = '(?P<Col2>.*)\|{2,}(?P<Col4>.*)\((?P<Col5>.*)\)'

In [60]: mydf = mydf.join(mydf.pop('Col2').str.extract(regex, expand=True)) \
                    .sort_index(axis=1)

In [61]: mydf
Out[61]:
  Col1 Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5
0   AA   AN  log1  Ind  0.9
1   AB   LN  log2  RED  8.9
2  AAC   RN  log3  RED  9.8
```

Comment: There's that `pop` again :-)

Comment: @piRSquared, sorry about that! 8-D

Comment: There are a few methods that are very natural that escape my memory when I could use them.  I'd like to cement `pop` in my mind so that it becomes part of the solution space as my brain spins around looking for an answer